# Java: Int won't change when instructed

Tags: java

Dungeon.java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Dungeon extends Character{
 public static void main (String[]args){
//Intro
  // Creating Relevant Objects
     Scanner Input = new Scanner(System.in);
     Character User = new Character();
     Test TT = new Test();
     Dice Rand = new Dice();
     Movement Move = new Movement();

  // Introduction
     System.out.println("Yo Yo Welcome To The Java Dungeon!");
     System.out.println("Let's Get This Party Started!");    

  // Name Input
     System.out.println("First Offf.. What Is Your Name?");
       User.CharName = Input.nextLine();
     System.out.println("Welcome " + User.CharName + "!");

  // HP Input
     System.out.println("Now Lets Get Your Health Points!");
       TT.Continue();
       User.CharHP =  Rand.Di();
     System.out.println(User.CharName + " Your HP is: " + User.CharHP);

  // Attack Input
     System.out.println("Now Lets Get Your Attack Points!");
       TT.Continue();
       User.CharAtk =  Rand.Di();
     System.out.println(User.CharName + " Your Attack Points are: " + 
User.CharAtk);

 // Dungeon Start!
     while (User.CharPos < 10 ){
         Move.Moving();


}

}



}
```

& Character.java

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

public class Character {
    String CharName = "blank";
    int CharHP = 0;
    int CharAtk= 0;
    int CharPos = 0;

}

class Movement{
 public void Moving(){
//Input Object
        Scanner Input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Character User = new Character();

//Test
        char test = 'g';
         System.out.println("You Are Currently On Level: " + User.CharPos);
         System.out.println("Enter E To Move Forward");
          test = Input.next().charAt(0);
           if (test != 'e' && test != 'E'){
                 System.out.println("You've Failed Already... You Fell Into 
    a Spiky AF Pit!");
                 System.exit(0);

                 } 

           else {
               User.CharPos++;
           }
    }
}
```

Whatever I do I can't get Int CharPos to increase by 1 each time the loop goes round. This is how I previously coded it but I can't see to get it to increment. Any times? There's another class I haven't included but it doesn't affect these two.

Comment: You are creating a new `Character` everytime `Moving` is called, so it starts from the initial value

Comment: *FYI:* [Java naming convention](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/2697/oracle-official-code-standard/9031/naming-conventions#t=201704081811142143014) states that names of local variables, fields, and methods should start with a lowercase letter. --- Also, your code is badly formatted (indented). --- Not following naming and formatting standards reduce human readability, and as a result, increases probability of coding errors.

Comment: Use a debugger. Had you done so, you wouldn't be asking this question.

Comment: Thanks UnholySheep that did the trick, I'll keep that in mind Andreas I'm still learning so :) I prefer humans to debuggers. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

@UnholySheep is right. To fix you issue, you need:
1) Convert `Character` inside `Movement` class to field, instead of creating new instance on each `Move` method call.
2) Create `Character` object ourside `Movement` and pass it to `Movement` class instance
3) retrive character fields using getters

```
class Movement{

private Character user;

public void setCharacter(Character user)
{
    this.user = user;
}

public Character getCharacter()
{
    return user;
}

 public void Moving(){
//Input Object
        Scanner Input = new Scanner(System.in);
        .....
        user.CharPos++;
        ....
```

And in other class:

```
public class Dungeon extends Character{
 public static void main (String[]args){
//Intro
  // Creating Relevant Objects
     Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
     Character user = new Character();
     Test tt = new Test();
     Dice rand = new Dice();
     Movement move = new Movement();
     move.setCharacter(User);
...
```